# Swift/UIKit- URLSession.shared.dataTask not executing completionHandler

Tags: swift, uikit, urlsession

So I'm still relatively new to Swift and have been trying to find a solution to this to no avail. Asynchronous code in particular has been giving me headaches. I recently came back to this project after maybe a month without touching it, and I swear this code had been working correctly beforehand.

I'm making a GET request to a local server in the viewDidLoad method of a UITabBarController. I can see my server receiving the request and outputting JSON so I know that isn't the issue. The UITabBarController contains two UICollectionViewControllers that reference the data from this request in their cellForItemAt method, however they're throwing an error because they're executing before the request is finished.

Despite the request itself having a completion handler and the method containing it having an escaping completion handler, my code continues executing instead of waiting on them and I'm just at a loss as to why this is happening. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code, kind of stripped down:

```
class TabViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GifController.getGifs(forDate: date){(gifs) in
               
                print("completion handler")
        }
}

class GifController{

static func getGifs(forDate date: Date, completionHandler: @escaping ([Gif]) -> Void){
//generates request
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
    print("eyyyyyy")

    if let data = data{
       //JSON logic
                
     do{
          let gifs = try decoder.decode(Array<Gif>.self, from: data)
                    
          print("Got \(gifs.count) gifs")
                    
          completionHandler(gifs)
                    
      }
     catch{
           print(error)
     }

   }
}
        task.resume()
}


class GifCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GifCollectionViewCell
        
        let index = indexPath.item
        
        print("cell for item at")
        
        //this instance variable is being written in the UITabBarController's viewDidLoad. It's throwing an index out of range error
        let gif = self.gifs[index]
 }
}
```

"completion handler" from TabViewController isn't being printed, neither is the "eyyyy" from GifController, or "got gifs" before "cell for item at" is printed and the index out of range error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

fixed this myself. I Added a check for an empty array in the cellForItemAt method, and then asynchronously reloaded the CollectionView on the main queue in the completion handler in TabViewController.